# reactjs in docker building react

Tags: reactjs, docker, networking

I have a problem I am building my reactjs app in a buildstep in docker and then using nginx to run it. However I can not get it to be able to connect to my api running in another container

The relevant parts of my docker-cmpose.yml are here

```
api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: "./api"
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./api:/app
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
      MYSQL_HOST_IP: mysql_db
    networks:
      - my-network

frontend:
    depends_on:
      - api
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      API_URL: http://api:3030/v1
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "8090:80"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./frontend:/app
    networks:
      - my-network
networks:
  my-network:
    name: my-network
```

The relevant bit from my Dockerfile is

```
COPY package.json ./
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm i && npm run build


# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And finally in my default.conf for ngnx I have

```
upstream api {
  server api:3030;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name xxxx.com www.xxxx.com

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /api {
            rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://api;
        }
    
}
```

The problem I am having is it wont resolve to the api

[image]

Please can anyone help me to get it to resolve to the ip/url for the api running in its container?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React application runs in a browser, and it can't use any of the Docker networking features.  In particular, since it runs in a browser, it can't resolve the `api` host name, which only exists in containers running on the same Compose network, and your browser isn't in a container.

You already have your Nginx setup to proxy `/api` to the back-end application, and I'd just use that path.  You can probably set something like `API_URL: /api/v1` with no host part.  Your browser will interpret this as a path-only relative URL and use the host and port the application is otherwise running on.

Comment: thank you! I was being stupid. Of course its client side this works